# Installation zabbix agent windows server 2012 how to solve?

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to install zabbix but it says to uninstall from my windows server. But his folder does not exist to be deleted[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94dOq.jpg)

I tried to search the folder and reinstall the files in different versions